# How to SELECT year using a WHERE clause on a DateTime type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

There is a table `Sales`with data from year 2005 to year 2015
I want to query data and filter column `Sales_Date` with `datetime` data type where the year is 2013 including all other columns

```
     SELECT *
     FROM Sales
     WHERE Sales_Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01';
```

is this correct or there is a function specifically to filter query by year of `datetime` data type

Comment: what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: i am using ms sql (ssms)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not correct as it includes data from 2014-01-01, which isn't a day in 2013.

Instead of between, which checks for a closed interval, use `>=` and `<` to search for an interval open at the end.

```
SELECT *
       FROM sales
       WHERE sales_date >= '2013-01-01'
             AND sales_date < '2014-01-01';
```

You could also use `year()` or `datepart()` to extract the year like in

```
...
WHERE year(sales_date) = 2013;
```

or

```
...
WHERE datepart(year, sales_date) = 2013;
```

But that will prevent any index on `sales_date` to be used, which isn't good in terms of performance. So it's not the best way to query that data, the first approach with `>=` and `<` is to be preferred.

Comment: Thank you Humble and helpful your knowledge will increase exponentially

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`year`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Sales
WHERE  YEAR(Sales_Date) = 2013;
```

Comment: `YEAR` is in every supported version of SQL Server @Zuuu . I can't remember if it was in 2005, so either you're using a very old version of SQL Server (and if so it's past time to upgrade, you need to be prioritising that), or you aren't using SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu it was introduced in SQL Server 2008

Comment: Then looks like the OP needs to look at upgrading; 2005 has been out of support for a few years now.